# Exception occuring when updating database schema in symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, docker, doctrine

I am pretty new to Symfony and Doctrine and as such have been playing around with a branch of some code which I will need to be working on commercially in the near future.

To cut a long story short I am at the stage now where I have amended an existing entity in order to add a new parameter. I have updated the ORM annotation to represent this, as I understand it if I run the following:

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

This should automatically update the database table to add a new column to accommodate my new property. However when I run it I get the following error:

```
 [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                                                                                      
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Its probably worth noting that the project is already communicating with the database successfully when you interact with it via forms in the browser so i'm rather confused why this error is appearing?

I am also running the database on a docker container, which I assume is probably contributing to this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the database settings set correctly in your `app/config/parameters.yml`?

Comment: Im an idiot... they hadn't been updated for my local machine. Thanks! Add this as an answer so I can accept it and give you some kudos.

Comment: I have posted this in an answer for future visitors. An error can be in a small corner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for symfony2 to be able to communicate with your database, you will need to set the correct parameters in `app/config/parameters.yml`.

On initial installation using `composer` the command line could also ask for these paramters (database, username, password and hostname).

No matter which method is used, at the long last you'll find them in `app/config/parameters.yml`.

Good luck!